# Телеграмм ссылки

Tags: ruby, telegram, telebot

Как заменить длинную ссылку одним словом в TELEGRAMM ?

пример :
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask ==>> ***задать вопрос***

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать `parse_mode: 'Markdown'`, работает такой синтаксис: `[ссылка](текст)`

```
bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, parse_mode: 'Markdown',
  text: "[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask](задать вопрос)")
```